# Why dateutil.parser does not work as expected?

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I'm trying get a `datetime` instance representing *April 23rd*, but always get *March 4th* if the argument passed is `'3.4'`, setting `dayfirst=False` is of no use:

```
In [115]: from dateutil import parser

In [116]: parser.parse('4-23', ) #√
Out[116]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 23, 0, 0)

In [117]: parser.parse('4/23', ) #√
Out[117]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 23, 0, 0)

In [118]: parser.parse('4.23', ) #×
Out[118]: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 4, 0, 0)

In [120]: parser.parse('4.23', dayfirst=False) #×
Out[120]: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 4, 0, 0)
```

is it a bug of `parser`?

Comment: Does the fuzzy option work? `parser.parse('4.23', fuzzy=True)`?

Comment: @Salixalba it doesn't

Comment: I'm still getting the same for: dt=parser.parse("3/13/2019", dayfirst=True), dt.day=13

Comment: @ShaniShalgi How can you have 13 for the value of the month? The parser assumes that you made an error, **which you did**, by passing in an invalid value for a month and attempts to correct that by invalidating the dayfirst parameter. See working example in edited answer below.

Comment: @Spade of course I know 13 is an invald month, but that is also why I expect to get an error for dt=parser.parse("3/13/2019", dayfirst=True), same as I would for dt=parser.parse("3/53/2019", dayfirst=True). It is one thing to offer corrections but another to automatically correct when I specifically ask for dayfirst. I have an OCR program that reads dates and if it makes an error, reading 3/13/2019 instead of, say 3/8/2019 I don't want this corrected for me. I have to write an elaborate program to undo this correction afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that a dot character is not supported as a separator between units of time by the parse method since it is used in the context of a time string represented in ISO format.

Please try converting all dots to slashes(/) or heifens(-)

```
parser.parse('4.23'.replace('.','/'))
```

to resolve this problem

**EDIT** (to address new comments):

Here is an example of this in action

> parser works as expected below:

```
>>> parser.parse('4/11/2019', dayfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('4/11/2019', dayfirst=False)
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 0)
```

> parser assumes errors on behalf of the invoker and attempts to auto-correct the issue by invalidating the `dayfirst` parameter:

```
>>> parser.parse('3/13/2019', dayfirst=False)
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 13, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('3/13/2019', dayfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 13, 0, 0)
```

There cannot be a 13th month and  therefore parser assumes that invoker incorrectly requested the `dayfirst` parameter - attempts to resolve the issue by invalidating the `dayfirst` instead of throwing an exception. This is another issue with this parser.

Comment: then is there some docs saying `.` is illegal to use? `parse('3.15.13')` is working well.

Comment: I know it's ok to use `/`, just asking why(or when) we should not use `.`

Comment: @Spade according to [documentation](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-1443e0f14ad5dff07efd465e080d1110920673d8-2) other separators, including `.`, are supported. And if it was not supported, module should rather fail to parse, but it does not.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: Sounds like you guys are right. It is a bug but the parse method tries to make sense of too many things including times represented in strings. `s = '''
    zhangxaochen found a bug with the dateutil.parser.parse method on March 21st 2014, 
    exactly at 11:45 pm with timezone -08:00."
    '''
print parser.parse(s, fuzzy=True)` . You found a way it breaks!

Comment: @Spade why you say *you found a way it breaks*? the example you showed runs well on my machine

Comment: @zhangxaochen - I said you found a way to break the parser. The dude to email and file a bug report with is Gustavo Niemeyer reachable at gustavo [at] niemeyer [dot] net